# What does it mean by "shapes building to a woman"?

Tags: meaning

"The painting still hangs--a vast, moon-filled abstract, shapes building to a woman, curves like rolling blue hills, lit from within and without."

I am not so sure about the description here.
When it says 'moon-filled', does it mean there are a lots of moons on the painting, or the moon is so large which fills the painting?
And what does it mean by "shapes building to a woman" and "curves like rolling blue hills"?
I just don't get it and I can't visualize the description.

Answer (score 0):

Moon-filled could suggest either shapes, or colors (lots of blues, like pale moonlight and contrasting indigo shadow).

"Shapes building to a woman" and "curves like rolling blue hills" both suggest lots and lots of sweeping curved lines defining the painting, instead of straight lines and angles.  The former would suggest something that defines an abstract womanly shape, curves converging together to suggest hips, breasts, limbs, whereas the "rolling hills" description would be curves that are layered to suggest successive hills receding into distance.

All in all, I'd like to see this painting, it sounds engaging and relaxing at the same time.